# Angular Bootstrap dropdown toggle breaks inputs in dropdown in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a bunch of dropdowns in a table that contain radio buttons. The radio buttons are generated from the result of an ajax request when the dropdown button is clicked.

I was having the problem that if you opened a dropdown while another dropdown was already open, both stayed open and it messed up the content of the first one. I fixed this adding

```
    $('.convert-dropdown .open').dropdown("toggle");
```

at the beginning of the ng-click function for the dropdowns. This worked great in Safari but in Chrome it makes the radio buttons unclickable (they are enabled but refuse to be checked, even if I add the checked property in the HTML.)

Anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: can you create a plunker and show the demo?